# trying to load data from another class using deserialization

Tags: java

I am trying to load data from a text file that was saved in another class. The following is the code I am using to load a file loader and select the file I would like to get the data from:

```
public static Customer browse()
{
    Customer browse = null;

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int chooserOption = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;

        try {
            File file = new File (chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));


        browse = (Customer) input.readObject();
            input.close();
       return browse;
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
   return null;
}
```

This is the code I am using for the button to load the data:

```
     Consultant consload = new Consultant();
     this.jTextField4.setText(consload.getConsultantID());

    Customer custload = Customer.browse();
    custload.setCID(consload.ConsultantID);
    this.jTextField4.setText(custload.getCID());
```

The data was saved from class Consultant and not I need to load it in the class Customer. The loader is working but when I select the file this error appears :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Consultant cannot be cast to Customer
at Customer.browse(Customer.java:162)
at CreateCustomer.jButton1ActionPerformed(CreateCustomer.java:202)
at CreateCustomer.access$400(CreateCustomer.java:11)
at CreateCustomer$5.actionPerformed(CreateCustomer.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Do you think I have some missing code? Because there are no error before running the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very self explanatory:

```
Consultant cannot be cast to Customer
```

Clearly, when you are **serializing** the data, it's getting **saved** as an instance of a `Consultant` class, not a `Customer` class. Thus, when you try to read the file, the `Object` returned by the `ObjectInputStream` returns a `Consultant`, not a `Customer`.

I think you should focus your debugging efforts on the saving process, not on the loading process.

Comment: I have 1 serialization and 2 deserializations, I have a saving button which works fine and a loading button which works fine too. So the issue can't be with the saving. Then I have a browse button which only gets only one variable from the text file instead of all of it.

Comment: The browse button should  get the ConsultantID

Consultant consload = new Consultant();
     this.jTextField4.setText(consload.getConsultantID());

Then transfer the data from the Consult ID to the CID 

Customer custload = Customer.browse();
    custload.setCID(consload.ConsultantID);

Then it will put the data that is now in the CID in the jtextfield4

this.jTextField4.setText(custload.getCID())